# Как сделать запись в json файл с python?

Tags: python, json, discord

Делаю бота экономики на discord.py, использую json для хранения 2х типов валют.
Код записи:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    with open('economy.json','r') as f:
        money = json.load(f)
    with open('economy.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(money,f)
    guild = ctx.guild.id
    author = ctx.author.id
    money[str(guild)] = {}
    money[str(guild)][author] = {}
    money[str(guild)][str(author)] = 0
    money[str(ctx.author.id)]['Bitcoin'] = 0
```

**Текст ошибки:**

```
Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\pyt\bot\chillzone\chillzonebot.py", line 52, in test
    money[str(ctx.author.id)]['Bitcoin'] = 0
KeyError: '427047904209928193'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '427047904209928193'
```

Код ошибки '427047904209928193' это айди пользователя.

Comment: Тут нет проблемы с записью json. Тут проблема в том, что вы пробуете обращаться к ключу в json, которого там нет.

Comment: А можете подсказать, как это решить?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Зачем вы пишите `money[str(ctx.author.id)]['Bitcoin'] = 0`, чего этим пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: с этим как раз никаких ошибок нету. Это дополнительная валюта, которая рандомно меняет курс каждые 2ч. Проще говоря усложнённая версия казино. Конкретно данная строка отвечает за запись кол-ва этой валюты у пользователя

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Проблема возникает именно в этой строке из-за того, что в файле `economy.json` нет ключа со значением `427047904209928193` (которое берется из `ctx.author.id`). Именно об этом говорит ошибка. Нет у вас файле записи для этого пользователя.